# Is it possible to emulate a NIC with software?

Tags: python, networking, arp

### Introduction

I'm trying to emulate a NIC using software (python), to do so I'm responding to ARP and ICMP packages. Is that even possible?

### Environment

I'm using Kali (2021.3) within VMWare (bridge NIC), python (3.9.7) and scapy (2.4.5).

eth0 interface:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.176.139  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.176.255
        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fee3:84e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:e3:08:4e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 14614  bytes 19043293 (18.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2504  bytes 259386 (253.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

### What I've tried

First started just by simply responding to ARP requests:

```py
from scapy.all import *

# Your network broadcast address
broadcastNet = "192.168.176.255"

macDict = { "192.168.176.182" : "60:01:94:98:97:c6",
            "192.168.176.183" : "68:c6:3a:a7:d3:40"}
            
# Use MAC address of this machine as source. If not eth0, change this:            
myMAC = get_if_hwaddr('eth0')

def handle_arp(packet):
    who_has = 1
    is_at = 2
    if packet[ARP].op == who_has:
        print(packet.summary())
        
        if packet.pdst in macDict:
            print("Sending ARP response for " + packet.pdst)
            reply = ARP(op=is_at, hwsrc=macDict[packet.pdst], psrc=packet.pdst, hwdst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff", pdst=broadcastNet)
            go = Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff", src=myMAC) / reply
            print(go.summary())
            sendp(go)
    return

def handle_icmp(packet):
    print(packet)
    return

# Sniff for packets.
sniff(filter="arp",prn=handle_arp)
```

Used `ping -c 1 192.168.176.183` to force an ARP, used wireshark and the ARP reply fired successfully:
[image: ARP reply]

However if I list my arp table it stands as incomplete:

```
arp -a
? (192.168.176.183) at <incomplete> on eth0
? (192.168.176.2) at 00:50:56:e6:c2:47 [ether] on eth0
? (192.168.176.254) at 00:50:56:ea:77:59 [ether] on eth0
```

At this point thought of using the same MAC address of `eth0` changing the `macDict` in the script:

```py
macDict = { "192.168.176.182" : "00:0c:29:e3:08:4e",
            "192.168.176.183" : "00:0c:29:e3:08:4e"}
```

However my arp table wasn't updated at all.

Finally tried creating a link interface:

```
sudo ip link add link eth0 address 56:8A:C0:DD:EE:FA eth0.1 type dummy
sudo ifconfig eth0.1 up
sudo ifconfig eth0.1
eth0.1: flags=195<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::548a:c0ff:fedd:eefa  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 56:8a:c0:dd:ee:fa  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6  bytes 420 (420.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

This last approach didn't work either.

Comment: Just to confirm: did your script print the expected output? The wireshark log shows a different MAC than the one your code says you would reply with.

Comment: @Kemp yeah you are right, I uploaded the wrong image, that was another attempt. Updated the post, the ARP shows the right MAC.